# How to create a modal pop-up containing an autocomplete box to select an entry?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, jquery-autocomplete

Is it possible to create some kind of modal box containing a JQueryUI autocomplete, in Javascript?

The user would click on an icon, the box would open, the user would select a value, the javascript would retrieve it and set it in a `<div>`.

If yes, how should I proceed? Any code example?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can use jquery's auto-complete functionality inside a jquery dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Just put the autocomplete input in the jquery dialog modal html, for example:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Search">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags" />
    </div>
</div>

<button id="open-search">Open search</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

And then just open the modal and set values on close:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    close: function() {
        var value = $("#tags").val();
        $("#result").html(value);
    }             
});

$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp"]
});

// Maybe use this on your icon, to open the modal.
$("#open-search").click(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
```

Here's the complete example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uvx8s/2/